# 21 Matchstick game in C#

Tags: c#

I am supposed to program a 21 matchsticks game in C# (The one where it's impossible for the player to win).

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Spiel 21");
            Console.WriteLine("========");
            Console.WriteLine("Nimm zwischen 1 und  4 Hölzer. Wer das letzte Holz nimmt, hat verloren.");
            Console.WriteLine("Du fängst an.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Streichhölzer auf dem Tisch: {0}", Hölzer);
            Console.Write("Wie viele Hölzer nimmst du? ");
            Spieler = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Computer = 5 - Spieler;
            Console.WriteLine("Ich nehme {0} Hölzer", Computer);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Hölzer = Hölzer - Spieler - Computer;
            Console.WriteLine("Streichhölzer auf dem Tisch: {0}", Hölzer);
            Console.Write("Wie viele Hölzer nimmst du? ");
            Spieler = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Computer = 5 - Spieler;
            Console.WriteLine("Ich nehme {0} Hölzer", Computer);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Hölzer = Hölzer - Spieler - Computer;
            Console.WriteLine("Streichhölzer auf dem Tisch: {0}", Hölzer);
            Console.Write("Wie viele Hölzer nimmst du? ");
            Spieler = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Computer = 5 - Spieler;
            Console.WriteLine("Ich nehme {0} Hölzer", Computer);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Hölzer = Hölzer - Spieler - Computer;
            Console.WriteLine("Streichhölzer auf dem Tisch: {0}", Hölzer);
            Console.Write("Wie viele Hölzer nimmst du? ");
            Spieler = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Computer = 5 - Spieler;
            Console.WriteLine("Ich nehme {0} Hölzer", Computer);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Hölzer = Hölzer - Spieler - Computer;
            Console.WriteLine("Streichhölzer auf dem Tisch: {0}", Hölzer);
            Console.Write("Wie viele Hölzer nimmst du? ");
            Spieler = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Du hast verloren.");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

It works well, but I just realised that I have to display the remaining matchsticks not as numbers but as actual lines.

Something like this:

Streichhölzer auf dem Tisch: |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

How can I link the number of sticks/lines to the calculation?

I apologize in advance for my command of the programming language. I'm pretty new at this as you can see.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haha ja kommt mir vor wie ne typische Studentenaufgabe :D

Comment: Ach kommt, die Hausaufgabe an sich habe ich ja schon gemacht :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PadRight` function of the `string` class:

```
Console.WriteLine("Streichhölzer auf dem Tisch: {0}", "".PadRight(Hölzer, '|'));
```

Comment: Wow that was simple but effective! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

`new String('|', 10)` returns `||||||||||`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is supposed to teach you loops. So to display a number of X Streichölzer you should loop X times:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < X ; ++i )
{
    Console.Write("|")
}
```

You could create a string from a character and a number of times it should be repeated, as well:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string('|', X));
```